# is it allowed to declared top level class as static in Java

Tags: java, akka, reactive-programming

I just started with Akka framework and  I saw the following piece of code in their [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/untyped-actors.html#untyped-actors-java). Can someone please explain this piece of code?

Is it allowed to declare top level class as static ?

I found a thread with [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3673630/static-class-in-java) question. It says that top level class can't be declared as static in Java but a top a top level code has been declared as static in this example! Am I missing anything?

```
static class MyActorC implements Creator<MyActor> {
    @Override public MyActor create() {
        return new MyActor("...");
    }
}

Props props2 = Props.create(MyActor.class, "...");
Props props3 = Props.create(new MyActorC());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NO.

Only class members can be `static`. And members include `fields`, `methods`, `nested classes`, `enums` ...etc.

But the class (top level) itself cannot be static (and it makes no sense for being static too).

And in the [documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/untyped-actors.html#untyped-actors-java) you refer, they have **not** mentioned `MyActorC` is a **top level class**, have they? (The import statements are in a different code snippet if you observe).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the fact that these are code snippets. You can't do `Props props2 = Props.create(MyActor.class, "...");` at the root level either. That code belongs inside a method.

Comment: Yup.  But it would help if the example was properly indented ... and showed the enclosing class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

No,
it's not allowed.
The access modifier supported for top level are class are as follows :

1) public

2)

3) abstract

4) final

5) strictfp.

Reason: Top level class

Because the static keyword is meant for providing memory and executing logic without creating Objects, a class does not have a value logic directly, so the static keyword is not allowed for outer class and mainly as mentioned above static can't be used at Package level. It only used within the Class level.